# .htaccess for codeigniter on DigitalOcean

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a problem on my DigitalOcean server. I am using Ubuntu. CodeIgniter returns to me 404 but on my localhost it is all fine. Here is my mod_rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /localhost/x/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Routes and Configurations are all fine.

Comment: Have you turned mod_rewrite on, on the server? What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: Yes, and I also did the sudo a2enmod rewrite but still to no avail. I am using 2.4.7

I also have restarted the apache2 service.

Comment: RewriteBase - usually is /

Comment: This what @Svetlio says - are you sure there is directory named `localhost`? On DO Ubuntu droplet by default you should have your web location in `/var/www/html` which is `/` in `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. Rename your controllers to have the first letter in upper-case.

example: main.php to Main.php

I don't know why, but it worked! Hope ths helps!

Comment: hey can give me some hints why use digital  ocean its only hosting like aws for database or more than aws @
Deviant Mark

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you forgot to enable mod_rewrite in the Apache .conf files use `sudo a2enmod rewrite` then `sudo service apache2 restart` to start 
mod_rewrite.

See Digital Ocean tutorial for more details:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04